# Show before AND after price for product with pricing rules (BigCommerce Website)

Tags: javascript, jquery, bigcommerce

My website sells the majority of our products wholesale (in bulk) and we are trying to refine our order processing system.

For our product prices we use the price per piece, and we have product options and rules set up for each product (the pack sizes vary) that add a percentage onto the product price when the buyer selects the pack size option.

There is only one pack size option for each product so we want to make the product option field invisible and set it to the pack size as default. It's extra work for our customers to select the option for each product, and since they can't buy without this option being selected, it's a bit pointless asking them to choose it.

The issue we have is that, when the option is selected, the price shown is for a pack. This is what the customer pays, but we also want to display the price per piece too, so they would see something like this:

Price per piece: £2.99
Pack of 4 price: £11.96

Ideally we want to be able to show both prices on all pages so the customer knows the pack size before they click onto the product page.

If it helps, we have the product option names set up as "Pack of 2", "Pack of 8", etc.

Does anyone know a way we can do this? Some of our competitors show this information so we know it's possible! We experimented with custom fields but this didn't work as the prices do not update when the customer selects a different currency.

Any help is appreciated! Our website is http://www.childrenswearwholesalers.com (you have to create an account to view products and prices). If anything doesn't make sense here please let me know, look forward to hearing people's thoughts on this!